# Typescript: How to extend a class using different type

Tags: typescript

So, I have a class that has many methods... deals with an entity let's call it entity.

```
class entity {
  entityName: string = '';

  getList(): any[] {
    someAPI + this.entityName ....
  }

  getOne(): any{
  }
}
```

And then I have couple of specific entities that are extended from

```
class person extends entity {
entityName: string = 'person';
}

class order extends entity {
entityName: string = 'order';
}
```

What I would like is to set the entity type for each of my new classes. So instead of inheriting

```
  getList(): any[] {
  }
```

On `person` class, I would get something like this

```
  getList(): IPerson[] {
  }
```

And for order

```
  getList(): IOrder[] {
  }
```

Is there a way I can set an interface type in each of the inherited classes (similar to the way I am setting the `entityName`?)

Comment: [Generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) is what you are searching for. Simply map a generic type on the ```entity``` class and specify it when you extends (```extends entity<IOrder>```).

Comment: @CarloCorradini is correct. You need something like `class entity<T>` with `getList(): T[]` and then `class person extends entity<IPerson>`

Comment: ```entity``` could also be an [**abstract** class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes)

Comment: @CarloCorradini please consider posting your comment as an answer so I can award it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) is what you are searching for.

Map a generic type on the entity class (possibly [abstract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members)) and specify it when you extends (`extends Entity<IOrder>`).

Code snippet:

```js
/* === Entity === */
interface EntityOptions {
    name: string;
    anotherOption?: any;
    anotherOptionWhyNot?: any;
}
abstract class Entity<T> {
    protected readonly entityOptions: EntityOptions;

    public constructor(entityOptions: EntityOptions) {
        this.entityOptions = entityOptions;
    }

    public getOne(): T {
        // Call to API ...
        console.info(`Calling API (one) ${this.entityOptions.name} ...`);

        // DO NOT COPY THIS!
        return {} as T;
    }

    public getList(): T[] {
        // Call to API ...
        console.info(`Calling API (list) ${this.entityOptions.name} ...`);

        // DO NOT COPY THIS!
        return [] as T[];
    }
}

/* === Person === */
interface IPerson {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
class Person extends Entity<IPerson> {
    public constructor() {
        super({ name: 'person' });
    }
}

/* === Order === */
interface IOrder {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
}
class Order extends Entity<IOrder> {
    public constructor() {
        super({ name: 'order' });
    }
}

/* ---------------- */
// ERROR: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.(2511)
// const entity = new Entity({ name: 'ItDoesNotWork' });

// Person
const person = new Person();
console.log(person.getOne());
console.log(person.getList());

// Order
const order = new Order();
console.log(order.getOne());
console.log(order.getList());
```

PS: You can find it also on the Typescript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAvFYKIHYBcCWCCelomAKCYgpgE4BmAhgMb6yIqoDyADsgPZwDOYA3tgJBykBbfAC4wbBITwBzANy9ScZggAWRRizgB+UQtRyeCpasLqkrAOrLUAOSXawuuQF9spAEbjCFBGHIAbUjYOeGQ0AB4AFQA+Ll4GQiV8cgR8ABMwQnxSVNY-dHwaNFNWNlEQ2mL2OTiAVzc-JHJfEoka5OZCAAoC0PomM3Yywr6NNgBKWJ4eFSQ2ADoeiv6SyDBFouWq3hda+sawKXwEOjh8TrHRCMmeYGAwAGFSPz8wBGYwAEEABQBJMDmAbweOQSsw-Pg5nhiMxOgADR7PaSfX5gTqsfATAAknBm83WIwG834Qic-wBsLG1SmtzAABE6GBrHQrvc6F8AJpgCIACR+AGUAIRAzIIGqEOBcUmBLn6HY8Bh1BpNQ4IAAyswQ50uAG0ALrXGkIl5vZF-AFzIEg9hgiFQmHwp4NOBSU2ohriLE45SzBbDSpEwT4UnmilUm53emM5kPNmcnn8oVTEViiV6hwcCJ62XYHagDAQMBfIhsVj5sBYXAEEgUKg-IuEEsS7g8JCpURwGoCNxEfTEkRiCTSZzYfyBDj1xtrAAeKTgqWCwzCdeLrBizYVeyaVs8bTeXQmzZ4bBqDCInU4YD7ogA5KeG6xr2AnJTtjnsNg81AC3RCKkiGWKzwFJq0oMAfh-P9CEmVt207btCH0VJSBSURaWQ-Bh1HIIwAg-98BnAp52oXol1wwg112JVmnYVp2n3a5jzvc9L0DG8Okgx9n2zXNwAAWn4gTBKE3jyxwGkYAAJQkugJNER44EUHxyEydCHAlPBxAUUDmGINSHA8CRvF8AIgjmToACYAFYAEZrLGD87m3Hx8VWU4AHdiNoZirzAa8fgQWlmHwNhbAQcwOgAa04l8HMLFc4BHFowDvScC3cuL7zgc45G3G05j8ZgpE6FLWDmFUTjOMYX1y8F8sK4r4rKo51XEc4YppMjEposB2P-NL8A8sjsq6ktaoKoresIJrjlONqctBMb6sm6aWs1KqZCAA).

Answer (score -2):

A simple and easy way to return self in extended classes is this

```
class Entity {
  entityName: string = '';

  getList(): this[] {
    return [];
  }

  getOne(): this {
    return this;
  }
}

class Person extends Entity {}

new Person().getOne(); // this
new Person().getList(); // Person[]
```

If this doesn't cut it, you would either have to you generic. or "reimplement" the functions needed.

```
  getOne(): anyTypeYouWant {
    super().getOne()
  }
```